# Searching a document in Elasticsearch on Zulu date format

Tags: elasticsearch, time

I have documents in elasticsearch that has a field called MsgTime. I am trying to execute a range query for the same. Here is what I have attempted so far

```
curl -X GET --header 'Content-Type:application/json' http:localhost:9200/myindex/_count -d '{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"MsgTime":{"gte": "2020-04-16T18:46:02.048Z",
"lte": "2020-05-18T18:46:02.048Z"}}}]}}}'
```

No matter what date ranges I give in the range I get the same number of counts, which I know is incorrect. What am I missing?

Example of an indexed document. I have more than a 100 million documents in the index.

```
          "EndTime" : "2020-05-18T18:44:07.000Z",
          "StartTime" : "2020-05-18T17:40:46.000Z",
          "RollID" : "812755",
          "MachineID" : "Y5BI",
          "PersonalID" : "1075",
          "JMSTopic" : "received",
          "Org" : "test",
          "status" : "processed",
          "MsgTime" : "2020-05-18T18:46:02.048Z"  --> This is the element I am trying to execute the range query on
```

Answer (score 0):

Could not replicate. Are you sure you're getting the same count with different ranges?

The `_count` response would look something like this:

```
{
  "count" : 1,            <-- this
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 25,         <-- not this
    "successful" : 25,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

You can use `?pretty` to get an indented response:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/zulu/_count?pretty" \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d'{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"range":{"MsgTime":{"gte":"2020-04-16T18:46:02.048Z","lte":"2020-05-18T18:46:02.048Z"}}}]}}}'
```